# Register all services based on IProcessor<> without having to write more code for each one

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

This must have been asked before so sorry but how do you register this little lot

```
IThingProcessor : IProcessor<Thing>
IOtherThingProcessor : IProcessor<OtherThing>
```

given that I have

```
ThingProcessor : IThingProcessor 
OtherThingProcessor : IOtherThingProcessor
```

I have this code to register

```
container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn(typeof(IProcessor<>))
            .WithService.Base()
```

But for some reason it will not register them, any ideas? I changed this based on feedback from Krzysztof, but it is not happening.

Answer (score 2):

`WithService.Base()`

[See the docs for more details.](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#_Base__5)

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof, I did a lot of rtfm, but I'm still having no luck, any ideas, common gotchas etc.?